# HTML5 Canvas drawImage results are always slightly darker than source video. How do I stop this?

Tags: javascript, canvas, video, html5-canvas, html5-video

I would like to freeze a frame of a `<video />` and modify it in a `<canvas />`. However, I've found the result of the canvas "drawImage" function is always slightly darker than the original video. This is noticeable when the canvas is placed over top of the original video, which is necessary for my purposes. I don't understand why this is the case. Is there any way to get around it?

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/atd8vbkg/

PS I tried mirroring the entire original video to a canvas, so the darkness would be consistent when I overlayed the frame. This worked for desktop, however the video to canvas mirroring in mobile safari was very slow/low FPS, and therefor not a viable solution.

Comment: Just a quick look at it, seems to me that there is more the issue of compression and innacurate extraction of data from the video that causes the slight shift in how its displayed. On my computer it looked more like the image was slightly moved rather than colour adjusted. Try adjusting the output size of the canvas so that it atleast has the exact same dimensions as the video, and play around with that.

Comment: That didn't work (at least on its own), however changing the video file to this webm resulted in a perfect canvas copy: https://jsfiddle.net/df1zr2uv/. I tried converting my own local mp4 files to webm but the darkening problem persisted. I have no idea what's different about the video file in the linked jsfiddle.

Comment: There is probably some video compression going on. Without much knowledge of the specific processes the functions in javascript go through I would just assume there is little to nothing to do about it. Consider that the files will have different encoders and decoders, and that the function to extract the image will have to translate the file in order to display it on the canvas.